# Selenium Webdriver java cannot select dropdown option

Tags: java, selenium

I have read and tried many replies to similar questions but I am still unable to select an option from a dropdown control.  My code:

```
//select a particular item in the returned list of companies from the company dropdown

Select oDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$wnCore$ctrlBrokerSelect$ddlSelectCompany")));

oDropdown.selectByVisibleText("broker1");
```

This always results in `Cannot locate option with text: broker1`
if I try selecByIndex or Value, the result is the same - the element cannot be found.

I have imported `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`;
Thanks for any help you may have to offer.

My apologies for making this more complicated...
I also tried `oDropdowm.selectByValue("1");`  but this also returns `"Cannot locate option with value 1"`

Comment: Can you please add the concerned HTML snippet of the dropdown ?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Micheal. Can you post your HTML snippet. I don't think the value you are trying to select exists in the DOM, when you are trying to select.

Answer (score 0):

**Since I don't see "broker1" as an option in the HTML snippet here, hence the error `Cannot locate option with text: broker1`.**

You can try the below code to **select by value**, alternatively (basing the code as per the HTML snippet provided):

```
Select oDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_wnCore_ctrlBrokerSelect_ddlSelectCompany")));
oDropdown.selectByValue("0"); //For selecting option with value '0'
oDropdown.selectByValue("1"); //For selecting option with value '1'
oDropdown.selectByValue("2"); //For selecting option with value '2'
```

### Edit 12/01/15

As I see, **the "value" attribute is not changing**, so the **prior code using "value" shall work**. Also, if you want to **select the option by visible text**, the below code should work for you.

```
try{
    //waiting 20 seconds to detect the visibility of the dropdown
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_wnCore_ctrlBrokerSelect_ddlSelectCompany")));

    Select oDropdown = new Select(element);
    oDropdown.selectByVisibleText("Anna Test Company");
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error while waiting for the element to be clickable: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I also tried o.Dropdown.selectByValue("1"); but it returned "Cannot locate option with value :1.

Comment: Okay. I think you've pasted the wrong HTML snippet then. Can you please right-click on the the dropdown, inspect using firebug then fetch the correct dropdown code ?

Comment: Here it is:
<select name="ctl00$wnCore$ctrlBrokerSelect$ddlSelectCompany" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$wnCore$ctrlBrokerSelect$ddlSelectCompany\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_wnCore_ctrlBrokerSelect_ddlSelectCompany" style="width:100%;">
 <option value="0">Select Company</option>
 <option value="1">afdvv</option>
 <option value="2">Albracht Insurance Agency, LLP</option>
 <option value="3">Anna Test Company</option>
 <option value="4">BB&amp;T Insurance Services, Inc.</option>
 <option selected=""5">Blue Grass Insurance Agency, Inc.

Comment: Thank you for the help but it still results in "cannot locate element with text: Anna Test Company.
Same result when using selectByValue.
I'm wondering if it could be a timing issue.  Perhaps the dropdown is not populated quickly enough before the select statement is run?

Comment: Okay.. That might be a possibility. I have edited the code again under **Edit 12/01/15**. Please check if that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your HTML snippet, there is no `"Broker1"` text for the option1.

Please give

```
selectByVisibleTest("Select Company")
```

and try again.

Comment: Yes, it was a timing issue! I added Thread.wait(2000): and it worked.
Thank you again for your help.  I do appreciate it.